# How to add the delay to the easy pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, easypie

I wonder if it's possible to specify a delay of starting the animation in Easy Pie Chart?
I added the `delay` parameter but it does not seem to work.

```
<div class="chart" data-percent="73" data-scale-color="#ffb400"></div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Easy Pie Chart -->
<script src="js/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
       $('.chart').easyPieChart({
                delay: 3000,
                barColor:'#f64c72'
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem myself as follows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
          setTimeout(drawBox1, 6200);
});

    function drawBox1(){
        $('.chart').easyPieChart({
            barColor:'#f64c72',
            lineWidth:20
        });
};
</script>
```